# How to setup Android client with Grails backend

Tags: android, grails

I am new to android development. Currently, i am using the ionic1 framework with JS and Angular1 for the client side. In Backend, I am using Grails running on Tomcat7 server with PostgreSQL database. Our ionic app works fine only thing is its performance is slow I am not able to use much of native platform functionality since app is very dynamic in nature

I am planning to change from ionic and angular to an android native app. Also, i want to use the same backend Groovy code. We are using rest APIs.

To set up the new app, can I just redesign the app in the android studio with Java and XML and call the necessary APIs from the backend directly from main_activity.java class or do I need to setup and re-configure the framework?

Comment: REST apis shouldn't care who comes calling for data, be it Angular, Java, Postman, or curl.

Comment: Thanks for your input, just to recheck: can I use java code from android studio independently to make an API call